# Can´t solve "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in a DataTable.Rows.CopyTo

Tags: c#, object, reference, copy

I can't seem to understand why I get:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

error in this situation :

```
    DataTable utenRomData;
    DataSet utenRomSet;


    private void InitDataUtenRom()
    {
        utenRomData = new DataTable("GjesterUtenRom");
        utenRomSet = new DataSet();

        utenRomData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FulltNavn"));
        utenRomData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("StartDato"));
        utenRomData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AntallDager"));

        utenRomSet.Tables.Add(utenRomData);


        if (File.Exists("gjesteInfo.xml"))
            utenRomSet.ReadXml("gjesteInfo.xml");

        utenRomData.Rows.Add(gjestenavnInput.Text, datoInnsjekk.Text, antallDager.Text);

        utenRomSet.Merge(utenRomData);
        utenRomSet.WriteXml("gjesteInfo.xml");
    }

    DataTable medRomData;
    DataSet medRomSet;

    private void InitDataMedRom()
    {
        medRomData = new DataTable("GjesterMedRom");
        medRomSet = new DataSet();

        medRomData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FulltNavn"));
        medRomData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("StartDato"));
        medRomData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AntallDager"));

        medRomSet.Tables.Add(medRomData);

        if (File.Exists("gjesteInfo.xml"))
            medRomSet.ReadXml("gjesteInfo.xml");

        DataRow[] temp = new DataRow[medRomData.Rows.Count]; 

        utenRomData.Rows.CopyTo(temp, 0); <- This is where I get the error!

        medRomSet.Merge(utenRomData);
        medRomSet.WriteXml("gjesteInfo.xml");
    }
```

I am trying to move content from table utenRomData to table medRomData with a drag and drop. Any thoughts?

How can I instance utenRomData in InitDataMedRom()?

Comment: There are only two options: `utenRomData` is `null`, or `utenRomData.Rows` is `null`. (If `temp` is `null` you'd get an `ArgumentNullException`, not a `NullReferenceException`.) You don't show the code where you initialize `utenRomData`, so you have to check yourself which one it is.

Comment: Have you checked how many rows are present in the medRomData? If it is zero (because the file doesn't exists or because the ReadXml has added a different table) what happen when you try to copy many rows to an empty array of datarow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `utenRomData` has no instance.

You can check if it has a value by:

```
if (utenRomData != null) {
   utenRomData.Rows.CopyTo(temp, 0); 
   medRomSet.Merge(utenRomData);
   medRomSet.WriteXml("gjesteInfo.xml");
}
```

To instantiate a new instance of `utenRomData` simply do:

```
if (utenRomData == null) {
  InitDataUtenRom();
}
```

Comment: Davis : *FacePlant* Offcourse! Can believe I missed that. But how can instantiate utenRomData when it is another method? I have updated the code. :)

Comment: @MariusMathisen - just add a check in to see if it is `null`, if it is, call `InitDataUtenRom` (I have updated my answer)

Comment: I am still having problems. I can´t seem to copy from one table in to another table inside the same XML file. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @MariusMathisen - you'll have to post it as a new question and state where exactly you're stuck (with any errors). I'll try and assist when I get some time.

Comment: Ok. Will create a new question now.

Comment: -This is my new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194793/i-am-trying-to-move-data-from-one-table-inside-a-xml-file-to-another-table-insid